# Utorrent stops downloading. Have to start it again

Tags: windows, utorrent

It is really annoying. I don't understand why this is happening. It is not in a queue. And I make sure to press the start right away option. Even so it just stops by itself a minute after being started. Any idea?

---

**UPDATE:**

Some extra info from another user with the same issue:
No matter what torrent file I add, it stops after a minute or less. Plus anything downloaded rolls back like nothing has been downloaded. I have even changed the download folder permissions using chmod 777.

Comment: Does it always stop or does it sometimes just become very slow?

Comment: If your internet is fine, and it's only the uTorrent that has this connection problem, uninstall uTorrent and download the last version of uTorrent. If the problem continues, check out [this](http://forum.utorrent.com/viewtopic.php?pid=671762) thread at the official utorrent forums, and [this](http://forum.utorrent.com/viewtopic.php?id=15992) speed & connection troubleshoot guide.

Comment: No, it just says "stopped". It happens like clockwork for every single torrent.

Comment: Do you have a scheduler turned on? What if you say force start?

Comment: Check the status to see if there is an error message (for example out of disk space). Is it a completed torrent? If so, has it already reached the configured ratio? What happens if you use *Force Start*?

Comment: @Synetech
Where can i check the Status??

Comment: @SyedHaiderHassan The status bar. It may (iirc) turn red when there's an error.

Comment: What version of uTorrent?

Answer (score 1):

Most common solution:

Uninstall it and install again the latest version. Make sure that there are no more than one version installed.

Comment: Unless you have set loads of configuration options, an uninstall and reinstall should always be the first troubleshooting step. Although it still may not resolve the issue - its always worth a try.

Comment: @leinad13 Right. I suggested this solution because it worked for me!